# $\int_0^t m(x) \ dx =\int_0^t n(x) \ dx $ for all t > 0 implies that m(x) = n(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^t m(x) \ dx =\int_0^t n(x) \mathrm{d}x $$
> For all $t > 0$.
> m and n are continuous.
>
> Prove that $m(x)=n(x)$

**MY APPROACH**
I took f(x)= m(x)-n(x). Assume that f(x) is not zero at j (wlog assume it to be positive). As f(x) is continuous , there exists $\delta >0$ such that $x \in (j-\delta,j+\delta) \implies |f(x)-f(j)| > f(j)/2$.
Thus we can say $\int_j^{j+\delta} f(x) \ dx >0$
$$\int_0^{j+\delta} f(x) \ dx =\int_0^{j} f(x) \ dx + \int_j^{j+\delta} f(x) \ dx$$

But that implies $\int_j^{j+\delta} f(x) \ dx  = 0$ . A contradiction.

Is the proof ok?

Comment: Only why is $f$ continuous? You never said that $m$ or $n$ is continuous....

Comment: Oh extremely sorry, it was said that it is continuous . Apologies for carelessness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function, then $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ is a $C^1$ function with the property $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Now if $f(x)=m(x)-n(x)$, then, by your assumptions, $F(x)$ is zero everywhere, which implies that $F'(x)=m(x)-n(x)$ is also zero everywhere, hence we can conclude the necessary result.

Comment: I'm fairly a beginner in calculus . Can you elaborate on the c^1 function part?

Comment: @LucyferZedd $C^1$ means that the function is continuous, derivable and its derivative is also continuous. This result on the integral is quite standard (and straightforward); you can find it in any textbook on calculus.